# Proving the non existence of a two disjoint spanning trees in a graph G specifying the below conditions.

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a connected graph on $N\geq3$ vertices such that if we delete all the edges of any cycle then the graph is not connected . Find the maximum possible number of edges possible .

> My Progress:

- I was able to get a hint from the answer which is $2N-3$ , that its related to $N-1 + N-2$ , so my motivation was to first consider the spanning tree $(T)$ of $G$ so if we can show that edges of $E(G)\setminus E(T)$ (that is edges remaining after deleting the spanning tree edges) are not possible to form a tree then maximum is $N-2$ edges for that , then in total we would have $2N-3$ edges . But how do we prove there is no tree possible in the remaining graph after we remove a spanning tree ?

Comment: It is impossible to disconnect a graph by deleting an edge that belongs to a cycle. What is your question, please explain

Comment: all edges i meant @QED

Comment: Your question starts with an assumption about the graph $G$. What do you intend to prove?

Comment: Sorry i just edit it , now hope its clear

Comment: The proving is i wrote below the method : and after that proof i will be able to solve the problem actual i think for max edges

Comment: This is an excellent problem! I suggest starting with a weaker claim: if $T$ is a spanning tree of $G$, then $G-T$ is at most a tree: it's a tree or a forest. (This gets you an upper bound of $2N-2$, which is one away from the $2N-3$ you want.) Then, you must prove that it's also impossible for $G-T$ to be a tree - in other words, if $G$ is the edge-disjoint union of two spanning trees, then we can find a cycle $C$ such that $G-C$ is connected. I used induction for this.

Comment: Nice way thanks i got it now but lastly can you give a bit more what you did to prove the inductive case ?@MishaLavrov

Comment: Never mind now underatood thanks @MishaLavrov